# Basic software to install on computers to be donated

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm currently setting up a small project where I'll be donating computers to kids and communities that need access to a computer but do not have one.

Before I donate these computers, I'll be installing Ubuntu. I'm only really familiar with Windows, so I have very little knowledge of Linux.

What I'm asking for is a bit of guidance. As Linux users, can you tell me what proper basic software that should be on the computer? I will be researching, of course, but it does not hurt to ask as well.

Thank you for your time and have a wonderful day!

Comment: I recommend you Edubuntu for that noble purpose.  

 https://edubuntu.org/

Answer (score 13):

I agree that Edubuntu can be a good alternative.

It also depends on the computers - older computers need a linux distro with a light desktop environment (ultra light Lubuntu, medium light Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu). I think Ubuntu Budgie is a light weight newcomer in the Ubuntu family.

See this link, [Old hardware brought back to life](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640)

Newer computers work well and are easy to use with standard Ubuntu.

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

-o-

If you have several similar computers, you can create a master system with the OEM method and install suitable program packages. After that you can clone it to each of the computers. Linux is very portable also as installed, if you avoid proprietary drivers (for graphics and wifi).

See this link, [Ubuntu OEM Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview)

Answer (score 4):

For older, low-resource systems, Abiword is a good substitute word processor over Libre Office Writer.  There's also a spreadsheet, Gnumeric, which is much lighter on system requirements than Libre Office Calc.  The two together will do the vast majority of the work you'd normally want an office suite for, will read and write Word and Excel files, and save a lot of space and performance on a machine for which Lubuntu is the better choice.  I've run these (in another low-requirement distro) on a 300 MHz Pentium class processor with as little as 256 MB RAM, and got satisfying results.

Comment: For those reasons abiword and gnumeric are the default in Lubuntu for these older machines.

Answer (score 3):

[Flavors](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) can be a powerful tool that can be used to set up a Linux environment for a particular need.

From that list, I would recommend [Edbuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/) as the best choice for this particular scenario. Directly from the Edbuntu page,

> Edubuntu is a grassroots movement, we aim to get Ubuntu into schools, homes and communities and make it easy for users to install and maintain their systems.

But, I suggest that you go through there and do some reading for yourself to try and see what you think would be the best fit for the kids and communities using the computers.